# why does index not work as expected in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I really want to why my index not working.

I have two table post, post_log.

```
create table post
(
    id         int auto_increment
        primary key,
    comment    int                  null,
    is_used    tinyint(1) default 1 not null,
    is_deleted tinyint(1) default 0 not null
);

create table post_log
(
    id         int auto_increment
        primary key,
    post_id    int      not null,
    created_at datetime not null,
    user       int      null,
    constraint post_log_post_id_fk
        foreign key (post_id) references post (id)
);

create index post_log_created_at_index
    on post_log (created_at);
```

When I queried below, created_at index works well.

```
explain
SELECT *
FROM post p
INNER JOIN post_log pl ON p.id = pl.post_id
WHERE pl.created_at > DATE('2022-06-01')
    AND pl.created_at < DATE('2022-06-08')
    AND p.is_used is TRUE
    AND p.is_deleted is FALSE;
```

When I queried below, it doesn't work and post table do full scan.

```
explain
SELECT *
FROM post p
INNER JOIN post_log pl ON p.id = pl.post_id
WHERE pl.created_at > DATE('2022-06-01')
    AND pl.created_at < DATE('2022-06-08')
    AND p.is_used = 1
    AND p.is_deleted = 0;
```

And below not working either.

```
explain
SELECT *
FROM post p
INNER JOIN post_log pl ON p.id = pl.post_id
WHERE pl.created_at > DATE('2022-06-01')
    AND pl.created_at < DATE('2022-06-08')
    and p.comment = 111
```

what is different between 'tinyint = 1' and 'tinyint is true'?

and, why first query work correctly and the others don't work correctly??

Comment: How large are your tables? What's the cardinality of the index?

Answer (score 0):

When making the query plan, MySQL has to decide whether to first filter the `post_log` table using the index, or first filter the `post` table using the `is_used` and `is_deleted` columns.

`= 1` tests for the specific value `1`, while `IS TRUE` is true for any non-zero value. I guess it decides that when you're searching for specific values, it will be more efficient to filter the `post` table first because there will likely be fewer matches (since these columns aren't indexed, it doesn't know that `0` and `1` are the only values).